# strpos and string in string searches

Tags: php, strpos

I have a comma delimited string and I need to be able to search the string for instances of a given string. I use the following function:

```
function isChecked($haystack, $needle) {
    $pos = strpos($haystack, $needle);
    if ($pos === false) {
        return null;
    } else {
        'return 'checked="checked"';
    }
}
```

Example: `isChecked('1,2,3,4', '2')` searches if `2` is in the string and ticks the appropriate checkbox in one of my forms.

When it comes to `isChecked('1,3,4,12', '2')` though, instead of returning `NULL` it returns `TRUE`, as it obviously finds the character `2` within `12`.

How should I use the strpos function in order to have only the correct results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function isChecked($haystack, $needle) {
    $haystack = explode(',', $haystack);
    return in_array($needle, $haystack);
}
```

Also you can use regular expressions

Comment: Worked like a charm, i now see where the logical mistake was.

Answer (score 2):

Using explode() might be the best option, but here's an alternative:

```
$pos = strpos(','.$haystack.',', ','.$needle.',');
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to do it may be splitting `$haystack` into array and compare each element of array with `$needle`.

Things used [except used by you like if and function]: 
[`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) 
[`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)
[`strcmp`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php)
[`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)

Funcion:

```
function isInStack($haystack, $needle) 
{
    # Explode comma separated haystack
    $stack = explode(',', $haystack);

    # Loop each
    foreach($stack as $single)
    {
          # If this element is equal to $needle, $haystack contains $needle
          # You can also use strcmp:
          # if( strcmp(trim($single), $needle) )
          if(trim($single) == $needle)
            return "Founded = true";        
    }
    # If not found, return false
    return null;
}
```

Example:

```
var_dump(isInStack('14,44,56', '56'));
```

Returns:

```
 bool(true)
```

Example 2:

```
 var_dump(isInStack('14,44,56', '5'));
```

Returns:

```
 bool(false)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Emmerman's use of in_array() is a lot more efficient than looping

Answer (score 0):

```
function isChecked($haystack, $needle) 
{
    $pos = strpos($haystack, $needle);
    if ($pos === false)
    {
        return false;
    } 
    else 
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Will this actually not just find the '2' in '12'? Will it solve the problem or is it just a restatement of it?